# CSS class auto suggestion in eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, netbeans

So far I have used netbeans, now I am planning to switch in eclipse , everything is fine but like in netbeans it doesn't provide me css class proposal. In netbeans if I use or write any css class , that class will be automatically appeared in css file as proposal even , in html/php file it shows class proposal from previously used class or class from framework like bootstrap , like the images below

**for css file**

[image]

**for php file**
[image]

But if I work in eclipse no css class or id proposal are showing . Like images below .

**for php file in eclipse**
[image]

**for css file in eclipse**
[image]
I am using eclipse mars  and WTP WebResources plugin is installed

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I tried both "Eclipse Neon for PHP" and "Eclipse Neon for JavaScript and Web Development". It refuses to show the CSS suggestions. Incredibly frustrating. If you figure it out, please shout it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Eclipse Web Toolkit Platform packages. You can do that either using the Eclipse Marketplace tool or Install New Software under the Help menu.

**WTP Tools in Eclipse marketplace**

[image: Eclipse Marketplace equivalent of WTP]

Or you can install the Genuitec Webclipse packages which provides a more robust web development environment for front end developers.

https://www.genuitec.com/products/webclipse/

Comment: I'd say this is more of a question/comment to the original poster than an actual answer.